# Flutter local json services

Tags: flutter, dart

I am developing a Quiz Game and I need to apply local json search services, I am having difficulties in applying the variables. I have been studying dart for a few weeks, and I am facing an error in the part of showing the result of json on the screen.

I would like some example of service with local json, or some light to continue the development. First of all, thank you.

Code Example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

class GameService extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    _GameServiceState createState() => _GameServiceState();
}

class _GameServiceState extends State<GameService> {

    List perguntas;
    List<dynamic> perguntaCurrent;

    Future<List> fetchPerguntas() async {
        var response = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/api/data.json');
        var perguntas = json.decode(response);
        return perguntas;
    }

    void getPergunta() async {
        var perguntaCurrent = await fetchPerguntas();
        var current = perguntaCurrent[10];
        setState(() {
            perguntaCurrent = current;
        });
    }

    @override
    void initState() {
        super.initState();
        this.getPergunta();
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(

            body: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                    Text(this.perguntaCurrent['pergunta']),
                    Text(this.perguntaCurrent['versiculo'])
                ],
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

i use this Json local:

```
[
    {
        "id":1,
        "pergunta":"O que Abel ofereceu a Deus?",
        "dificuldade":1,
        "respostas":[
            "Verduras",
            "Leite",
            "Frutas",
            "Uma ovelha"
        ],
        "certa":4,
        "referencia":"Gênesis 4:4",
        "versiculo":"Abel, por sua vez, trouxe as partes gordas das primei­ras crias do seu reba­nho. O Senhor aceitou com agrado Abel e sua oferta..."
    },
    {
        "id":2,
        "pergunta":"Quantas pessoas entraram na Arca de Noé?",
        "dificuldade":1,
        "respostas":[
            "9 pessoas",
            "7 pessoas",
            "6 pessoas",
            "8 pessoas"
        ],
        "certa":4,
        "referencia":"Gênesis 6:10 e 7:7",
        "versiculo":"E gerou Noé três filhos: Sem, Cão e Jafé. Noé entrou na arca, e com ele seus filhos, sua mulher e as mulheres de seus filhos, por causa das águas do dilúvio."
    },
]
```

Comment: What is the error and what part of the code is throwing it?

Comment: Hi, in this part Text(this.perguntaCurrent['pergunta']),

Comment: Compiler message:
lib/services/services.dart:44:32: Error: A value of type 'String' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'int'.
                                        Text(this.perguntaCurrent['pergunta']),

Comment: It sounds like the error might be coming specifically from `this.perguntaCurrent['pergunta']`. Are you sure `perguntaCurrent` is a `Map` rather than a `List`?

Comment: This part var current = perguntaCurrent[10]; Bring a json object

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet is to parse the JSON into an object before even trying to use it. Dart has a JSON generator, or you could use an online service like this: https://app.quicktype.io/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is coming from these lines:

```dart
Text(this.perguntaCurrent['pergunta']),
Text(this.perguntaCurrent['versiculo'])
```

or more specifically, these bits:

```dart
this.perguntaCurrent['pergunta']
this.perguntaCurrent['versiculo']
```

You are attempting to access `perguntaCurrent` with a String key. However, you have declared `perguntaCurrent` as `List<dynamic>`, which accepts `int` keys only.

(Not knowing the structure of the incoming JSON nor what you're trying to do with `perguntaCurrent`, I don't have a suggestion of what you can do instead. Hopefully this is enough information for you to figure out your own solution, though.)

Comment: @SHARKDEV I'm still not sure what you're trying to do so I don't know what to recommend. All I can say is you are trying to treat a `List` like a `Map` and it isn't going to work.

Answer (score 0):

Change `List<dynamic> perguntaCurrent;` to `Map<String, dynamic> perguntaCurrent;`